# Docker & Docker Compose - COPY for prod image but mount volume for dev

Tags: node.js, express, docker, docker-compose, google-compute-engine

I'm building a small NodeJS/Express app that I'm Dockersing and deploying to Compute Engine. I have my `docker-compose.yml` set up for development (i.e. I'm mounting my source directory so I can make changes without rebuilding).

When I'm ready for production I'll be building my image and pushing it to a container registry on Google Cloud. When I do so, I'd like to bake my source code into the image. Note: this is a one-man project and I'm not setting up any kind of CI. I can do this with `COPY` in my `Dockerfile` but I use the same `Dockerfile` for development. Is it OK to use a different `Dockerfile` for production and development or is there a method for me to do this conditionally within the `Dockerfile` itself? Something like...

```
if ENV=production
  COPY blah ./
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Best Practice is to keep separate docker files for production, development, and testing
The reason is that there can be different environments use for those 3 stages and it's easy to maintain in the long run

Always keep your docker file minimal and use .sh scripts for logical work

Comment: Thanks Kalanamith. Actually I was able to do both (copy and mount) with no side-effects, therefore only needing a single `Dockerfile` and making use of `.dockerignore`.

Comment: @PeterLudlow is there any way you could provide more details on the solution you found for this problem?